# MountVolume.Setup failed for volume "xxx": couldn't get secret

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm using AKS(v1.20.9).
I'm trying to deploy a StatefulSet that uses azure file share as a PV in my cluster.

My pod is stuck at `ContainerCreating` state and I'm getting the following error :

```
│   Warning  FailedMount       8m57s (x2 over 8m58s)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "buy-vol" : Couldn't get secret ns1/app-buy-secret                                                                                                                                  │
│   Warning  FailedMount       6m55s                  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[buy-vol], unattached volumes=[buy-vol│
```

My PV and PVC were created successfully :

```
kubectl get pv/app-buy-azure-file -n ns1
NAME                  CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                          STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
app-buy-azure-file   200Mi      RWX            Retain           Bound    ns1/app-buy-azure-file                           14m
```

My secrets are created via `SecretProviderClass` (since the secrets are saved in Azure Key Vault) and are available via kubectl :

```
kubectl get secret/app-buy-secret -n ns1
NAME                              TYPE     DATA   AGE
app-buy-secret   Opaque   5      16m
```

Under the secret I got the keys `azurestorageaccountkey` and `azurestorageaccountname` :

```
kubectl describe secret/app-buy-secret -n ns1
Name:         app-buy-secret
Namespace:    ns1
Labels:       secrets-store.csi.k8s.io/managed=true
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
azurestorageaccountname:  23 bytes
app-secret:                   36 bytes
tenant-secret:                  37 bytes
azurestorageaccountkey:   88 bytes
```

What might be the issue here ?

The StatefulSet yaml :

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-statefulset
  labels:
    {{- include "..labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  serviceName: {{ .Chart.Name }}-service
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "..selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "..selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
        aadpodidbinding: ״app-buy-binding-selector"

    spec:
      serviceAccountName: {{ include "..serviceAccountName" . }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}

          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /mnt/secrets-store
              name: secrets-vol
              readOnly: true
            - mountPath: /app/store/ 
              name: buy-vol

      volumes:
        - name: secrets-vol
          csi:
            driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
            readOnly: true
            volumeAttributes:
              secretProviderClass: {{ .Chart.Name }}-secret-provider-class

        - name: buy-vol
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: {{ .Chart.Name }}-azure-file
```

Role and RoleBinding to ServiceAccount :

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  name: {{ .Release.Namespace }}-ns-reader
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["configmaps", "pods", "services", "endpoints", "secrets"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]

---
{{- if .Values.serviceAccount.create -}}
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: {{ include "..serviceAccountName" . }}-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
    name: {{ include "..serviceAccountName" . }}
    apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: {{ .Release.Namespace }}-ns-reader
  apiGroup: ""
  {{- end -}}
```

If needed, I can add also the yamls of the pv/pvc...

Comment: I think serviceacoount for pods is not created, Please check what is the service account used for pod and check if that service account exists or service account does not have authorization to access the secret (rolebinding/clustrerolebinding)

Comment: Why you think the serviceaccount is the issue here ?

Comment: error: ```Couldn't get secret ns1/app-buy-secret```  from the output secret is present on the system so other obvious reason could be that service account does not have authorization to read it .

Comment: The service account exist and should have access to the secrets (I can access the other keys in the secret without the pvc/pv. I'm adding the yamls of the role binding of the service account

Comment: role & rolebinding seems to be fine , is it similar to issue mention in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/99061

Comment: Yeah I saw it, but I'm using a version that should have a fix to this issue (1.20.9)

Comment: In addition, I specify in the PV creation the namespace under the azureFile section (ns1) so this issue sounds different - if you dont mention the namespace, it searches for it in the wrong namespace